# Replace items in a dict of nested list and dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there any solution to replace items with a specific value in a `dict` of nested list and dicts in python ?

for example:

**Input** :

```
item_to_be_replaced =  'a'

replaced_with = 'z'

di = {"a": "A", "b": "B", "c": [2, 4, 6, {"a": "A", "b": "B"}], "d": {"a": [2, 4, 6], "b": [5, 2, 1]}}
```

**Output**:

```
{"z": "A", "b": "B", "c": [2, 4, 6, {"z": "A", "b": "B"}], "d": {"z": [2, 4, 6], "b": [5, 2, 1]}}
```

which is the most optimal way to solve this problem ?

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: It seems like you want to replace keys of dictionary if its the your question. then you can not replace key in dictionaries. alternatively you can first delete item and then add new one.

Comment: @Carcigenicate i need a recursive function which takes a 'dict, new_item, old_item' and returns a dictionary which replaces all the item which is present in that dictionary (ie, either key,values, values inside lists etcc...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive function that creates a new nested dictionary, replacing a key value with a different value

```
def replace_key(elem, old_key, new_key):
    if isinstance(elem, dict):
        # nested dictionary
        new_dic = {}
        for k, v in elem.items():
            if isinstance(v,dict) or isinstance(v, list):
                new_dic[replace_key(k, old_key, new_key)] = replace_key(v, old_key, new_key)
            else:
                new_dic[replace_key(k, old_key, new_key)] = v

        return new_dic

    elif isinstance(elem, list):
        # nested list
        return [replace_key(t, old_key, new_key) for t in elem]

    else:
        return elem


di = {"a": "A", "b": "B", "c": [2, 4, 6, {"a": "A", "b": "B"}], "d": {"a": [2, 4, 6], "b": [5, 2, 1]}}

print(replace_key(di, 'a', 'z'))
```

**Output**

```
{'z': 'A', 'c': [2, 4, 6, {'z': 'A', 'b': 'B'}], 'd': {'z': [2, 4, 6], 'b': [5, 2, 1]}, 'b': 'B'}
```

**Performance Comparison (using Jupyter Notebook) **

*Result: ComplicatedPhenomenon post has the fastest time by 10X over other two methods.*

**1. Reznik Post--JSON load substitution**

```
   %timeit json.loads(json.dumps(di).replace('a', 'z'))
```

23.6 µs ± 2.05 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

**2. DarrylG--Recursive Function**

```
%timeit replace_key(di, 'a', 'z')
```

20.1 µs ± 424 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

**3. ComplicatedPhenomenon Post--specialized to particular structure**

```
%%timeit
d = {"a": "A", "b": "B", "c": [2, 4, 6, {"a": "A", "b": "B"}], "d": {"a": [2, 4, 6], "b": [5, 2, 1]}}
d['z'] = d.pop('a')           
d['d']['z'] = d['d'].pop('a')      
d['c'][3]['z'] = d['c'][3].pop('a')
```

2.03 µs ± 211 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

Comment: You cannot relay on timeit, it cache alot of things, and your answer takes twice as much memory :)

Comment: @reznik--I thought timeit was the recommended approach for timing especially [since it was improved](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9643)

Comment: @Reznik--as a sanity check I reran the benchmarks using time 10, 000 loops and got similar results.  Are there other suggestions you have for timing?

Answer (score 2):

I dont thing its the best option, but when i saw this i thought about this answer:

```py
import json
json.loads(json.dumps(di).replace(f'"{item_to_be_replaced}"', f'"{replaced_with}"'))
```

Simple convert into string, replace the thing that i need to replace, and back to `dict`