# How to replace None values in JSON response?

Tags: python, json

I'm fetching financial information from an api endpoint and when I get a 200 response through

```
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()
```

It'll return `None` for all `null` values. How do I convert all `null/None` values to `0`? Since it's financial data, the JSON is usually quite massive (300k-400k lines, some with deep nested `nulls`) so I can't do a `try/except` block on each `TypeError`.

An extract of the json response looks something like this:

```
{'0': 
'Highlights': {'QuarterlyRevenueGrowthYOY': 0.671, 'GrossProfitTTM': 3750684, 'DilutedEpsTTM': 0.2, 'QuarterlyEarningsGrowthYOY': 0.95
5}, 'Valuation': {'TrailingPE': 60.75, 'ForwardPE': 0, 'PriceSalesTTM': 2.0817, 'PriceBookMRQ': 4.207, 'EnterpriseValueRevenue': 1.
806, 'EnterpriseValueEbitda': 0.0952}, 'Technicals': {'Beta': None, '52WeekHigh': 12.35, '52WeekLow': 7.84, '50DayMA': 11.0197, '20
0DayMA': 10.2209, 'SharesShort': 0, 'SharesShortPriorMonth': 0, 'ShortRatio': 0, 'ShortPercent': 0}, 'SplitsDividends': {'ForwardAn
nualDividendRate': 0.18, 'ForwardAnnualDividendYield': 0.0151, 'PayoutRatio': 0.9, 'DividendDate': '0000-00-00', 'ExDividendDate':
'2020-06-11', 'LastSplitFactor': '', 'LastSplitDate': '0000-00-00'}, 'Earnings': {'Last_0': {'date': '2020-06-30', 'epsActual': 0.1
9, 'epsEstimate': None, 'epsDifference': None, 'surprisePercent': None}, 'Last_1': {'date': '2019-12-31', 'epsActual': 1.86, 'epsEs
timate': None, 'epsDifference': None, 'surprisePercent': None}, 'Last_2': {'date': '2019-06-30', 'epsActual': -0.82, 'epsEstimate':
 None, 'epsDifference': None, 'surprisePercent': None}, 'Last_3': {'date': '0000-00-00', 'epsActual': 0, 'epsEstimate': 0, 'epsDiff
erence': 0, 'surprisePercent': 0}}, 'Financials': {'Balance_Sheet': {'currency_symbol': 'EUR', 'quarterly_last_0': {'date': '2020-0
6-30', 'filing_date': None, 'totalAssets': '12810000.00', 'intangibleAssets': '281000.00', 'otherCurrentAssets': '60000.00', 'total
Liab': '4225000.00', 'totalStockholderEquity': '8585000.00', 'deferredLongTermLiab': '74000.00', 'otherCurrentLiab': '1274000.00',
'commonStock': '80000.00', 'retainedEarnings': '311000.00', 'otherLiab': '200000.00', 'goodWill': '3381000.00', 'otherAssets': '730
00.00', 'cash': '4983000.00', 'totalCurrentLiabilities': '4025000.00', 'shortLongTermDebt': None,
... 
}
```

Yeah you get the point.. a ton of `None` all over the place. Any quick fixes for this?

Comment: What do you want to replace `None` with? Do you just want to remove the items in the dictionary?

Comment: To `0` (integer), as stated in the question

Comment: Write a function that goes through all values in the dictionary, and would check for a `None` variable. If that is true, then grab the value within the keys of the dictionary and replace the dictionary’s value with `0`.

Comment: How many child nodes? Can you post a valid JSON sample

Comment: Since json size is your concern, consider using a streaming parser for json, which won't load a object model for the entire JSON at once.

Comment: Why treat this as a JSON problem? You could also ask how to replace `None`s in a Python map without the question having anything to do with JSON at all.

Comment: If you take out the JSON part, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59336397/replace-items-in-a-dict-of-nested-list-and-dicts; do the JSON parsing first, then apply the approach from that answer, and you're done.

Comment: Note that your current example is hard to work with, because it isn't syntactically valid -- someone can't copy-and-paste it to check their answers. A good [mre] is the shortest possible thing that **reproduces the exact problem you need help with** when run without changes. Needing to come up with someone's own sample data that just follows a demonstrated pattern breaks the "without changes" part of that rule.

Comment: FYI -- my answer was tested with the data subset at https://ideone.com/VBP1Dk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do it, @Charles Duffy, thanks for the inspiration - borrowed some but couldn't get it quite to work. The final code looks like this if anyone would need it in the future

```
from collections.abc import Mapping, Iterable


def replace_none_values(noneVal, replaceVal='0.00'): # not sure if this is bad practice 
    if noneVal is None:
        return replaceVal
    if isinstance(noneVal, Mapping):
        return {k: replace_none_values(v, replaceVal) for k, v in noneVal.items()}
    elif not isinstance(noneVal, str) and isinstance(noneVal, Iterable):
        return [replace_none_values(v, replaceVal) for v in noneVal]
    return noneVal
```

Comment: FWIW, the original data doesn't have any lists, which is why I didn't bother to support them -- part of the importance of having a representative sample included in the question is to allow concrete acceptance tests for answers. That said, I'm glad you've got something that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
def recursive_replace(obj, findVal, replaceVal):
  for k, v in obj.items():
    if v == findVal:
      obj[k] = replaceVal
    elif isinstance(v, dict):
      obj[k] = recursive_replace(obj[k], findVal, replaceVal)
  return obj

result = recursive_replace(json.loads(yourdata), None, 0)
```